# How to call back (like onActivityResult) after launching activity from browser by clicking url?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, callback, android-activity

I succeded to call activity from browser link with tag like this.

```
<a href="myapp://launch.myapp.com/activity2?var1=linkClicked">my app</a>
```

of cource I added actvity setting in AndroidManifest.xml like this.

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2" >
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
         <data android:host="launch.myapp.com" android:scheme="myapp"
         android:pathPrefix="/activity2"></data>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I want to call back from the activity2 with a value.

Is there any way to receive some value from the activity that was launched by the browser like above?

In other words I want do something like onActivityResult in the browser and
get a value from the activity and set the value on the web page which has launched the activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are looking for. But this might work for you.

You could do something like this:

From the activity, you opened from Browser, write that data 2 file or save it to data base. 
And then from webpage/browser retrieve that data.
You can also serialize that data either.

"DER ISS ALWAZ AN ALTERNATIVE WAY OF DOIN THINGS"

Comment: Thanks for your answer on my question. But, how can I read data file with javascript in the browser? And How can I do something in the browser when "activity2" finishs().